# PowerShell Write-Zip not preserving directory structure

Tags: powershell, zip, 7zip, pscx

I'm trying to create one Zip-file which contains everything in that directory (files & folders) and that preserves the directory structure.

By looking around on the net I see that lots of people have issues with this. So to make it easy on myself I installed the modules from `pscx` which contain the CmdLet `Write-Zip`.

**Folder structure**

```
- S:\TopFolder
- S:\TopFolder\Folder1
- S:\TopFolder\Folder1\SubFolder1
- S:\TopFolder\Folder1\SubFolder1\Stuff1.txt
- S:\TopFolder\Folder2
- S:\TopFolder\Folder2\SubFolder2
- S:\TopFolder\Folder2\SubFolder2\Stuff2.txt
```

**Tested code**

```
$Test = Get-ChildItem -Recurse 'S:\TopFolder\*'
Write-Zip -Path $Test -OutputPath 'S:\Zippie.zip' -IncludeEmptyDirectories

$Test = Get-ChildItem -Recurse 'S:\TopFolder'
Write-Zip -Path $Test -OutputPath 'S:\Zippie.zip' -IncludeEmptyDirectories
```

**Result in 'Zippie.zip'**

```
SubFolder1
SubFolder1\Stuff1.txt
SubFolder2
SubFolder2\Stuff2.txt
```

As you can see it's not sticking to the correct folder structure as `Folder1` and `Folder2` are missing. Is there something obvious I'm missing here? Because this issue has been reported as [fixed and verified](https://pscx.codeplex.com/workitem/7221).

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After getting some help from Dave Wyatt on [PowerShell.org](http://powershell.org/wp/forums/topic/problem-using-write-zip/#post-18260) it's fixed now.

The correct syntax seems to be:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse 'S:\TopFolder' |
Write-Zip -OutputPath 'S:\Test\Zippie.zip' -IncludeEmptyDirectories -EntryPathRoot 'S:\TopFolder'
```

Comment: Just in case anyone gets the same problem as I did running this or a similar script - EntryPathRoot is case sensitive to path that is piped into it. So `Get-ChildItem -Recurse 'S:\TopFolder' |
Write-Zip -OutputPath 'S:\Test\Zippie.zip' -IncludeEmptyDirectories -EntryPathRoot 's:\topfolder` will produce an error saying "Skipping [file]. It is not under the entry path root [path].